# Return values and original key from multidimensional array

Tags: php, algorithm, data-structures

I have a multidimensional array storing discounted price and discount type. Here's a basic example:

```
$discountNew[0]['price'] = 10;
$discountNew[0]['type'] = 'happy hour discount';
$discountNew[1]['price'] = 8;
$discountNew[1]['type'] = 'profile discount';
$discountNew[2]['price'] = 16;
$discountNew[2]['type'] = 'category discount';
$discountNew[3]['price'] = 6;
$discountNew[3]['type'] = 'medical discount';
```

I need a way to return the lowest price - and the associated discount type. In the above example that would be '6' and 'medical discount'.

I can find the lowest price by using **min** and **array_column** functions, like so:

```
$lowestPrice = min(array_column($discountNew, 'price'));
```

However, how can I return the discount type? I figured if I can find the key value of the original array (in the example above that would be 3), I can use that to look up the discount type. However, I can't find a way to return the original key, as array_column produces a new array.

As such, the question would be: How can I return the discounted price, plus either the discount type  or the original array key?

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: What if you have two products with the same price ? What would you return ?

Comment: Good question! It doesn't really matter, it could just be the first one in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If the prices are unique, then get the key for the lowest price and use it:

```
$lowestPriceType = $discountNew[array_search(min($price = array_column($discountNew, 'price')), $price)]['type'];
```

Broken down:

```
$prices = array_column($discountNew, 'price')
$lowestPrice = min($prices);
$key = array_search($lowestPrice, $prices);
$lowestPriceType = $discountNew[$key]['type'];
```

Comment: Thank you!
This solution worked for the basic example, but on a bigger array it fails - it returns the wrong discount type. I'm guessing this could be because the prices are NOT always unique..?

Comment: Yes, if "happy hour" and "category" discounts are both price 10, which should be chosen?

Answer (score 1):

```
$discountNew = [
  [ 'price' => 10, 'type' => 'happy hour discount' ],
  [ 'price' => 8, 'type' => 'profile discount' ],
  [ 'price' => 16, 'type' => 'category discount' ],
  [ 'price' => 6, 'type' => 'medical discount' ],
];

$result = array_reduce(
  $discountNew,
  fn($carry, $item) => $item['price'] < $carry['price'] ? $item : $carry,
  [ 'price' => max(array_column($discountNew, 'price')) + 1, 'type' => '' ]
);
```

Comment: That's a creative way to solve this. Interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will find it for you

```
$discountNew[0]['price'] = 10;
$discountNew[0]['type'] = 'happy hour discount';
$discountNew[3]['price'] = 6;
$discountNew[3]['type'] = 'medical discount';
$discountNew[1]['price'] = 8;
$discountNew[1]['type'] = 'profile discount';
$discountNew[2]['price'] = 16;
$discountNew[2]['type'] = 'category discount';


$lowestPrice = min(array_column($discountNew, 'price'));

foreach ( $discountNew as $dis ){
    if ( $dis['price'] == $lowestPrice ) {
        $type = $dis['type'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by problem solving technique as well

```
$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$min_key = 0;
foreach ($discountNew as $key => $discount) {
   if ($discount['price'] <= $min) {
        $min = $discount['price'];
        $min_key = $key;
   }
}
$min_discount_type = $discountNew[$min_key]['type'];
```